# Use SQL in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relation like this.

```
class Food < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_foods
  has_many :categories, through: :category_foods
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_foods
  has_many :foods, through: :category_foods
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class CategoryFood < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :category
  validates :food_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

How can i write code to find a Food(example name is a) that has its Category(example name is b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work

```
Food.joins(:categories).where(name: 'a', categories: { name: 'b'})
```

If you don't want the exact search you can make use of `LIKE`

```
Food.joins(:categories).where('foods.name LIKE :a AND categories.name LIKE :b', a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

> 'a' is not known :). We know 'b' and from that we find 'a'

In that case

```
Food.joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: 'b'})

# OR

Food.joins(:categories).where('categories.name LIKE :b', b: 'b'})
```

Comment: i think it can't be work.  we have to category_foods, don't we?

Comment: 'a' is not known :). We know 'b' and from that we find 'a'

Comment: Rails takes care of that notice that we have through association

Comment: You need to replace 'a' and 'b' with the names

Comment: i don' t understand. My work is from a category i must show all foods that have that categoriy. do you understand?

Comment: I didn't exactly get what you are trying to say in the comment above

Comment: ohhh. This work . But why we don't need use Category_Foods?

Comment: Rails internally create inner join on that if you check the query

Comment: You don't need to use it in rails query

Comment: Ohh. If i only wants to get foods.name how i do?

Comment: `Food.joins(:categories).select('foods.name').where(categories: { name: 'b'})`

Comment: Thank you very much :)))